# How to parse complex List with internal Dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm new to Python and looking for help from experts.

I have a JSON and able to parse it and when I dumped the data it is a List and within it there is a Dictionary.

How do I loop over each element and also pull the internal Dictionary key and values.

As you can see "subset" within the list is a Dict.

```
json_data=[{'location_id': '1',
  'location_state': 'Arizona',
  'subset': [{'location_name': 'Windsong',
    'location_city': 'Phoenix',
    'location_country': 'USA'}]},
 {'location_id': '10',
  'location_state': 'Georgia',
  'subset': [{'location_name': 'Buckhead',
    'location_city': 'Atlanta',
    'location_country': 'USA'}]}]
```

Comment: whats your expected output? what have you tried so far and what didnt work?

Answer (score 0):

using two fors you can take the data from the list inside the dict

```
for data in json_data:
    for a in data['subset']:
        print(data, a)

or

this way you can take only the dict
[x['subset'][0] for x in json_data]
```

Answer (score 0):

its not quite clear what your trying to do, if you want to merge the keys from the sublist into the keys in the main dict and drop the sublist then you can do it like below. This assumes you dont want to change your original `json_data`. if your happy changing it then you dont need to deep copy to a new list.

```py
from copy import deepcopy

json_data=[{'location_id': '1',
  'location_state': 'Arizona',
  'subset': [{'location_name': 'Windsong',
    'location_city': 'Phoenix',
    'location_country': 'USA'}]},
 {'location_id': '10',
  'location_state': 'Georgia',
  'subset': [{'location_name': 'Buckhead',
    'location_city': 'Atlanta',
    'location_country': 'USA'}]}]

merged_data = deepcopy(json_data)
[data.update(data.pop('subset')[0]) for data in merged_data]

print("###original###")
print(*json_data, sep="\n")
print("###merged###")
print(*merged_data, sep="\n")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
###original###
{'location_id': '1', 'location_state': 'Arizona', 'subset': [{'location_name': 'Windsong', 'location_city': 'Phoenix', 'location_country': 'USA'}]}
{'location_id': '10', 'location_state': 'Georgia', 'subset': [{'location_name': 'Buckhead', 'location_city': 'Atlanta', 'location_country': 'USA'}]}
###merged###
{'location_id': '1', 'location_state': 'Arizona', 'location_name': 'Windsong', 'location_city': 'Phoenix', 'location_country': 'USA'}
{'location_id': '10', 'location_state': 'Georgia', 'location_name': 'Buckhead', 'location_city': 'Atlanta', 'location_country': 'USA'}
```